# Why Can't I Call Skip on an IOrderedQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am returning an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` like so:

```
response.Data = Expressions
    .ApplySorts(request, result)
    .Skip(request.Skip)
    .Take(request.Take)
    .ToList();
```

Here is my class which contains a method to return an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

```
public static class Expressions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplySorts<T>(
        DataRequest request, IQueryable<T> items)
        {
            var sorts = request.Sort;

            if (sorts != null)
            {
                foreach (var sort in sorts)
                {
                    items = items.OrderBy(sort.Field + " " + sort.Dir);
                }
            }

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)items;
        }
}
```

But at runtime I get this error:

> {"The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to
>   Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method
>   'Skip'."}

Note that there are no sorts currently taking place; however, the return value of `ApplySorts<T>()` should still be returning the type that `Skip()` expects, no?

Answer (score 8):

You need a default sort. While in most databases, you can do `TOP`, `LIMIT` or `BETWEEN` without sorting, it doesn't *really* make sense (the first two actually apply to `Take`, but the theory is the same).

The order in which rows are returned is *undefined* (even if they usually appear in the order they were inserted). Therefore, your ORM is preventing you from creating a bug in your code (that is, the `Skip` is not consistent, and doesn't truly make sense).

To explain further: `Skip(10)` does not make sense without an `Order`, and it is functionally equivalent to not existing.  Whether or not we skip 10 rows is irrelevant if we don't have ordering. If you shuffle a deck of cards, discard the top 10, and then take 5, is it any different from simply taking 5 without discarding? In both cases, you get 5 random cards - the discard is irrelevant.

You should have a default sort case if there are no sorts provided. A suitable candidate is the table's primary key.

Comment: This is what I suspected, too.  I was hoping there was a way to apply a sort without knowing the entity's key.  Do you know of any?  Maybe something like `var key = t.GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(Key)));`

Comment: @user1477388 Without reflection (or having all entities inherit from a base class which exposes the primary key), I don't think it's possible. You might try `.OrderBy(i => 1)`, but even if that were to work, it would raise questions as to whether or not `Skip` and `Take` makes sense. It appears to me that you're paging data, and so the request *should* provide an ordering. Otherwise, your paging functionality will not work properly.

Comment: @user1477388 Yes, if you have attributes defined on your properties, it definitely is possible

Comment: Yes, your suggestion seems to work.  I would rather add this one line as you suggested `items = items.OrderBy(i => 1);` than checking whether or not to add `Skip()` everywhere.  I tried editing your answer showing the functional code, but the change was rejected.  Adding as separate answer.

Comment: @user1477388 I reverted the edit as, while the sample may compile, it is not a *real* solution to the issue; it is simply avoiding it (as per my comments)

Comment: @user1477388 That's just making the code not error, but also not function properly.  It is in no way a fix.

Comment: @Servy In what way does the code not function properly?

Comment: @user1477388 Ordering by `1` will trick the ORM into thinking your ordered the dataset. However, you are *still* getting a random dataset back. Paging will work "usually", but not always. The first time you call Skip, you make get rows 10-20. The second time you call it, you may get rows `1,2,3,42,35,63-67` - which is not the way you want to page data.

Comment: @user1477388 Your pagination is getting an entirely random set of elements each time, rather than the first N items, followed by the next N items, and so on.  You could get the same N items each time if you use such a meaningless sort, for example.

Comment: OK, thanks, I looked it up an SQL doesn't provide a default sort order in absence of a specified sort order.  I will update my answer to use TKey or something similar.  I thought it would use primary key as default.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection to get the key of `T` will be useful to pass as the default sort parameter since SQL will not provide one otherwise:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplySorts<T>(DataRequest request, IQueryable<T> items)
{
    var sorts = request.Sort;

    var keyProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop => 
        prop.IsDefined(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute), false));

    if (sorts != null)
    {
        foreach (var sort in sorts)
        {
            items = items.OrderBy(sort.Field + " " + sort.Dir);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        items = items.OrderBy(keyProperty.Name); // set a default sort if there are no sorts provided
    }

    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)items;
}
```

Comment: This is simply suppressing the *entirely valid error* that SQL is giving you to tell you that skipping on unordered data isn't a sensible operation (because its not).  Providing an ordering that doesn't actually order the data prevents the error *without fixing the problem*.

Comment: @Servy Good point; thanks for your response.  Updated with working code to get key of `T` via reflection and pass to dynamic `OrderBy()`.  I should probably make it null safe...

Comment: Btw, what's the `OrderBy` method that you are using - apparently is not the standard one? Looks like the one from `System.Linq.Dynamic`, but then you are using it incorrectly, it will order by the **last** field only.

Comment: @IvanStoev Are you saying `OrderBy(string sortExpression)` won't chain like `OrderBy(lamda)`?  And, yes, it is from System.Linq.Dynamic.

Comment: I'm saying it **will not** chain exactly as `OrderBy(lambda)` **does not** chain. With "normal" LINQ you chain multiple fields by using `OrderBy` ->  `ThenBy` -> ... -> `ThenBy`. In Dynamic LINQ you need to build a string like "Field1, Field2,..., FieldN" and pass it to a single `OrderBy` call.

Comment: @IvanStoev Wow thanks for that realization.  Feel free if you have time to update my answer (for the good of the coding community, too!).  I will likely update it, too, if you do not.  I have a lot of other work to do right now, though!